# How to get Mongodb parent Model tree structure using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$athar = $c_users->findOne($source) -> parent;
var_dump($athar);
```

The following error occured on above code:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\result.php on line 38</i>
```

Actually, I want to find the parent of a tree in mongodb. In mongodb shell     this command `("db.hammad.findOne({"name":"Bodington"}).parent")` works fine, but its alternative for PHP doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your `mongo` shell command is accessing a field from a [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/) that is returned by [findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/). It is not a special 'tree' or 'parent tree', simply a field called 'parent' and the document that is returned by `findOne` has a field called 'parent'.

In PHP, you could access a field from `findOne()` result, for example:

```
$doc = $c_users->findOne($source)["parent"]
```

Now, you may store the content of a tree structure in a field called 'parent' however this by no means a special structure.

See [MongoDB: Data Models Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) for more information on modelling data structures.

Comment: Thanks. it is working. i really appreciate your work.